# pass variable number of different arguments and call the function in c++

Tags: c++

I have three function pointers which have to be called from another class, the arguments number was fixed. now the requirement is to have any set of arguments for the handler functions. the following is a sample code:

```
struct TestUnit
{
        string _idStr;
        string _descStr;
        int _result = 0;
        string _errorStr;

        std::function<int(void)> _setupHandler =   [this] () { cout << "TestFramework: "<<_idStr<<" setup default" << endl; return 0; };
        std::function<int(void)> _runTestHandler = [this] () { cout << "TestFramework: "<<_idStr<<" run default" << endl; return 0; };
        std::function<int(void)> _postRunHandler = [this] () { cout << "TestFramework: "<<_idStr<<" post run default" << endl; return 0; };

        TestUnit(string id, string description, std::function<int(void)> setupHandler,
                        std::function<int(void)> runTestHandler, std::function<int(void)> postRunHandler):
                        _idStr(id), _descStr(description), _runTestHandler(runTestHandler)
        {
                if(setupHandler != nullptr)   _setupHandler = setupHandler;
                if(postRunHandler != nullptr) _postRunHandler = postRunHandler;
        }

        void runTestUnit()
        {
                if(_setupHandler() != 0)
                {
                        std::cout << "Test : " << _idStr << " setup failed, returning" << std::endl;
                        return;
                }
                std::cout << "Running Test : "<< _idStr << std:: endl;
                _result = _runTestHandler();
                if(_postRunHandler() != 0)
                {
                        std::cout << "Test : " << _idStr << " teardown failed, returning" << std::endl;
                        return;
                }
        }

};
class TestDriver
{
        int _setup()
        {
        }
        int _twoParams(int x, int y)
        {
        }

        vector<TestUnit*> _testsVector;

        public:
        void runAll()
        {
                #define ADD_FUNCTION(func) std::bind(&TestDriver::func, this)
                auto addTest = [this]
                        (string id , string description, std::function<int(void)> setupHandler,
                                std::function<int(void)> runTestHandler, std::function<int(void)> postRunHandler)
                {
                        TestUnit* testunit = new TestUnit(id, description, setupHandler, runTestHandler, postRunHandler);
                        _testsVector.push_back(testunit);
                };


                addTest("NO_ARGS", "no args test", nullptr,
                        ADD_FUNCTION(_setup), nullptr);

                //addTest("TWO_PARAMS", "two params", nullptr,
                //      ADD_FUNCTION(_twoParams), nullptr);


                for(auto testUnit: _testsVector)
                {
                        testUnit->runTestUnit();
                }
        }
};
```

In the commented lines, now I am trying to pass two arguments, what changes should i make to pass that? Also, the requirement is any number of arguments in the future of any type. although the return type is going to be same. ignore the memory leaks, this is just a sample code.

Comment: Where are those `x,y` parameters supposed to come from? You've made things hard on yourself by using that macro, it would probably be easier to just bind `x,y` as well. Then the bound function no longer has extra parameters.

Comment: I can chose not to use the macro for these functions, directly use bind but what changes should i make in the class

Comment: Something like `std::bind(&TestDriver::_twoParams, this, 1,2)` ? That of course binds `x=1, y=2`.